# Dual monitors, but different brands/models

Tags: multiple-monitors

I used to have two dual 23" monitors, but I went on an extended vacation to my parents one summer and needed a monitor, so I brought one with me. They live across the country so it was a hassle to transport a monitor, so I just ended up leaving it there.

So I've just been going with the one monitor lately, but I miss the increased productivity that dual monitors provided me.

I'd like to get another monitor, but I can't decide if I should just get the same brand/model as the other (if I can even find it anywhere) or not.

Does anyone else have "mismatched" monitors (different models/sizes)? Is it annoying?

Comment: I had highly mismatched, and it was "more space" and it was annoying, but better than nothing.  I now have partly mismatched, and it is even "more space" and it is not as annoying. What kills me sometimes is they are mismatched technology/age, and no amount of calibrations will set the colors the same. I would get a matching unit, but the favorite of the 2 is discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Lots of people use missmatched monitors, but whether its annoying is subjective. I was using a old 17 inch crt with a laptop, and you can't get more mismatched than that.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on your usage and preferences.

It's certainly possible to have monitors of different size; in my case I find it works quite well. I've got my main 24" with 1920x1200 on the right and a secondary 19" monitor (different brand, 1280x1024 resolution) off to the left.

```
        |---------|
|------||         |
|      ||         |
|      ||         |
|------||---------|
```

It certainly comes in handy to keep something open on the smaller monitor while doing my main work/browsing/gaming/whatever on the larger one.

Personally, I find nVidia options for managing multiple monitors better than ATI, but that's just my experience. The thing that's sometimes a bit odd is that when you drag a window from one monitor to the other, you have to make sure it will "fit" if moving to the lower resolution (and that it doesn't get "caught" on the top left corner of the larger monitor). Also, depending on pixel density, they may scale differently, so the same window on my 19" looks larger physically than on the 24". But if you're aware of these gotchas, however you end up configuring them, it's still a benefit to have the extra screen real estate. Something like UltraMon helps make things easier as well.